# Interact with StackNavigator's navigationOptions from view inside of TabNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How can I make `navigationOptions` interact with view inside of `TabNavigator`?

for example, from this question [**how do I access a component's state from `static navigationOptions`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098153/681830), I can make `navigationOptions` responsive to component's `state`.

But what if I want to make it responsive a step further, responsive to component's `state` inside of `TabNavigator`?

As image shows below, I want to make `Next` button enabled only if more than one checkbox get checked.
[image]

But there's no effect to provide `headerRight` in my component.

```js
export class CreateGroupCamera extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { state, setParams, navigate } = navigation;
        const params = state.params || {};

        return {
            headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' },
            headerRight: <Button title='Next' disabled={params.validator ? !params.validator() : true} />
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer myself after try error 3 hours...

follow these steps you can have a workable version.

### 1. Instead of expose `TabNavigator` directly, wrap it.

```js
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    ...
});

export class TabView extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<Tabs />);
    }
}
```

### 2. Pass callback function down with `screenProps`. When called, `setParams()` into `navigationOptions`.

```js
export class TabView extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
        const { state, setParams, navigate } = navigation;
        const params = state.params || {};
        return {
            headerRight = <Button title='Next' disabled={params.validator ? !params.validator() : true} />
        };
    }

    _validator(validator) {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({validator});
    }

    render() {
        return (<Tabs screenProps={{ callback: this._validator } />);
    }
}
```

### 3. Inside main component, pass function with `screenProps.callback`.

```js
_validator() {
    return this.selectedDevices().length > 0;
}

render() {
    return (
        <Checkbox onChecked={ () => {
            this.props.screenProps.callback(this._validator);
        }} />
    );
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Val I will contact and have issue you can see in message box .https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150909/discussion-between-kirit-modi-and-val

Comment: Ok I'll look into it 12 hours later =)