# How to make "Go back to initial StackNavigator Screen when TabNavigator's Tab is pressed"

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

#### Intro

Just like Facebook, Instagram, and any other mobile app, I want to implement 'go back to initial screen in Stacknavigator'

1. if user press the button,
2. it goes back to the very first page.

#### Simple Use Case

1. see TabNavigator
2. Goes to 'Feed' Tab
3. Goes to 'User' Screen
4. Goes to another 'User' Screen
5. PRESS the Main Tab Icon - 'Feed'}
6. Goes BACK to 'Feed' Tab // so you won't see the 'back' button

And please leave a comment if you don't understand this use case, I will draw its state flow for you

**Code for the icon on my Main TabNavigator.**

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
          const { routeName } = navigation.state;
          ....
          return (
              <TochableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{navigation.goback(iconName)}> 
              // undefined is not a function when I press the Button 
              // deeper screen. (not getting any error on Main)
                  <Ionicons
                      name={iconName}
                      size={30}
                      style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
                      color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}
                      />
             <TochableWithoutFeedback>
         );
  },
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991396/resetting-the-navigation-stack-when-changing-tab-stacknavigators-nested-in-tabn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

actually, it depends on how many deep is your routing like Instagram 2 to 3 deep routing else are tabs

so you can reset your router or go back to the main router by using

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
```

for eg.

Tab navigation child ahs Stack navigation so in Stack, you can do something like

```
// Anyone watching this, please check your react-navigation version
// I'm using ^1.0.0-beta.21.
// props for tabBarOnpress varies can be varied (Editor John Baek)
tabBarOnPress: ({scene, jumpToIndex}) => {
      jumpToIndex(scene.index)
      navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
          NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'home' }) // go to first screen of the StackNavigator
        ]
      }))
    }
```

so whenever someone press Home Tab then all route reset and you see Feed screen  just like Instagram

```
TabNavigation 
  -Home
      |
      StakeNavigation 
                    |
                    mainScreen //main of home 
                    Subrouts 
                    RouteToProfile //just like insta

  -Search 
        |
         StakeNavigation 
                       |
                       mainScreen //main of search 
                       searchResult //if people serch some specific
```

and go on...  so reset route at stakeNavigation level of Tab

```
const SubHome = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Home2: { screen: Home2 },
  Home3 : { screen: Home3 },
},{
  navigationOptions:({navigation,screenProps})=>({
    tabBarLabel: I18n.t('tab_car'),
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <CustomIcon name={'Home'} width={28} height={30} fill={tintColor} />
    ),
    tabBarOnPress: (tab, jumpToIndex) => {
      jumpToIndex(tab.index)
      navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
          NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' }) // go to first screen of the StackNavigator
        ]
      }))
    }
  }),
  headerMode:'none'
});
```

Comment: This post explains how to call `navigation.dispatch` from `navigationOptions` . https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098153/681830

Comment: my code is really live for my application dont just everything its just for example use only TabBarPress

Comment: avigationBar disappear coz of headerMode:'none'

Comment: umm.. one more twist i have this issue in my application so i found solution here     "react-navigation": "https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git#ee2e27c24bc1f0b2d5076ffe8385b39943de7e65",

Comment: i am using specific version of navigation for tab click

Comment: yeap. upgrading react-navigation to beta.21 solved the problem. Now it says `undefined is not a function. (jumpToIndex(tab.index)`. I don't understand why it's `undefined`.

Comment: use this version https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git#ee2e27c24bc1f0b2d5076ffe8385b39943de7e65

Comment: I'm struggling with these problems! Please help!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050248/how-to-dispatch-multiple-actions-in-react-navigation

Comment: AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-all-screens-when-user-logs-out-scroll-and-page-index

Comment: I think you can solve this problem (+200 bounty) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-tabnavigator-when-user-logs-out-from-other-screen