# How to dispatch multiple actions in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, redux-thunk

I want to perform two actions but it doesn't work.

```
const backAction = NavigationActions.back({
    key: null
})
const dispatchLogoutAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: "LoginView"})]
});
nextProps.navigation.dispatch(backAction);
nextProps.navigation.dispatch(dispatchLogoutAction);
```

What other ways to dispatch both actions in `react-navigation` rather than listing dispatch statements parallelly?

Comment: This is continuous problem from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-all-screens-when-user-logs-out-scroll-and-page-index

Comment: Further question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059045/how-do-we-call-the-specific-type-of-action-in-react-navigation

Comment: Why do you want to dispatch two actions at once? Probably then what you want to do should go into one action that you then dispatch?