# How do we call the specific type of action in react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How to call action using NavigationAction???

Here if the user doesn't have a token, it goes back to the initial page. **I want to reset(initialize) the `MainTabNavigator`.**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if ( nextProps.token == undefined || _.isNil(nextProps.token) ) {
      const backAction = NavigationActions.back({
        key: null
      })
      nextProps.navigation.dispatch(backAction);
```

Here is MainTabNavigator. I added route to reset everything when 'MyCompleteReset' is triggered.

```
export default TabNavigator({ ........ });

const navigator = MainTabNavigator;
const defaultGetStateForAction = navigator.router.getStateForAction

navigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  if (action.type === 'MyCompleteReset') {
     // For your custom action, reset it all
     return defaultGetStateForAction(NavigationActions.init())
  }
  // Handle all other actions with the default handler
  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state)
}
```

How do we call the `MyCopmleteReset` action???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-all-screens-when-user-logs-out-scroll-and-page-index

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050248/how-to-dispatch-multiple-actions-in-react-navigation

Comment: This is continuous problems from the links above