# Resetting the navigation stack when changing tab (StackNavigators nested in TabNavigator)

Tags: react-navigation

I have two StackNavigator. Movies:

```
const MoviesStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Movies: Movies,
  MovieDetails: MovieDetails,
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Movies',
})
```

and actors:

```
const ActorsStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Actors: Actors,
  ActorDetails: ActorDetails,
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Actors',
})
```

I am using them inside a TabNavigator:

```
const RootTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Movies: {
    screen: MoviesStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Movies'
    }
  },
  Actors: {
    screen: ActorsStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Actors'
    }
  },
})
```

When the user changes tab, I want him to arrive to the root component of that tab (Movies or Actors), not to a stacked component (MoviesDetails or ActorsDetails). In other word, when a user quits a tab, the StackNavigator in that tab should be resetted to the root component.

My first approach was to use `StackActions.reset` when initializing the root component in a tab to try to reset the other tab (that the user just quit) but the library prevents interacting between navigators, at least in that way.

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution was to use `tabBarOnPress`:

```
const RootTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Movies: {
    screen: MoviesStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Movies',
      tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}: any) => {
        navigation.navigate('Actors')
        defaultHandler()
      },
    }
  },
  Actors: {
    screen: ActorsStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Actors',
      tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}: any) => {
        navigation.navigate('Movies')
        defaultHandler()
      },
    }
  },
})
```